# Saving/exporting selected features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, features, select-by-attribute, select-by-location

I would like to save my attributes selection as a layer. I have read on other posts to do it by selecting the layer with the attribute selection, then right clicking on it and choosing "save selection as...". However, by right clicking on the layer with selected attributes, there is no "save selection as..." in my case.

[image]

How can I save/export the attribute selection as a new file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## For QGIS 2.x versions

You are doing fine, but just need to go to next step.

[image]

Tick on `Save only selected features`.

Comment: I get "Creation of layer failed (OGR error: Attempt to create csv layer (file) against a non-directory datasource.)" The features are from a PostGIS database.

Answer (score 2):

## For QGIS 3.x versions

Let's assume there is a polygon layer called *'grid'* with its corresponding attribute table, see image below.

[image: input]

Select a feature (or features) that has (have) to be saved/exported.

[image: selection]

And then by beans of `RMB` over the layer *'grid'* use `Export > Save Selected Features As...`

[image]

---

**References:**

- [How to Save a Selection as a New File Using QGIS](https://www.gislounge.com/save-selection-new-file-using-qgis/)
- [Select, Save/Export feature as a new layer using QGIS 3.2.1](https://www.igismap.com/select-save-export-feature-as-a-new-layer-using-qgis-3-2-1/)