# Splitting up GeoJSON into multiple shapefiles using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geojson, features, splitting

I have a layer (GeoJSON) with multiple features. I want to split the layer up into multiple shapefiles using QGIS.

I don't want a file for each individual feature. Is it possible in QGIS to select features and cut and paste them to a new file?

Comment: Select features, then right click the layer and choose to export only the selection.

Comment: @Erik How do I select a feature? I am new to QGIS.

Comment: Please have a look at the [QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/) and tutorial, basics are covered there.

Comment: If you can give us more specifics we could help you further. Do you want to select based on an expression? What kind of dateset are we dealing with here?

Comment: Which shapefile do you want to split?  You start by saying you have a GeoJSON file, where does the shapefile come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was not clear to me how the features have to be split and saved, e.g. only selected or simply all. Hereupon I am providing several possibilities that may answer the question.

**Case 1.** When certain features have to be selected and exported afterwards

Check the following articles:

- [How to Save a Selection as a New File Using QGIS](https://www.gislounge.com/save-selection-new-file-using-qgis/)
- [Saving/exporting selected features in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259931/saving-exporting-selected-features-using-qgis)
- [Select, Save/Export feature as a new layer using QGIS 3.2.1](https://www.igismap.com/select-save-export-feature-as-a-new-layer-using-qgis-3-2-1/)

Exactly what @Erik mentioned in his comments.

**Case 2.** When all features have to be exported

Let's assume there is a polygon layer called `'grid'` with its corresponding Attribute Table, see the image below.

[image: input]

In the attribute table, there is a unique attribute, for example `"ID"`, otherwise create it using `@row_number` in the Field Calculator.

Proceed with ["Split vector layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#split-vector-layer) can be found in `Vector > Data Management Tools > Split Vector Layer...` using the `"ID"` as *'a Unique ID Field'*.

And get the output

[image: output]

*Note:* Mind that every single output will be temporal and in `.gpkg`-format.

**Case 3.** When all features have to be exported but they possess an attribute in common.

It can be done the same way as was done on *Step 2*. Nevertheless, there is an additional way described in this thread: [Dividing shapefile into multiple shapefiles using an attribute value in QGIS Graphical Modeler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357776/dividing-shapefile-into-multiple-shapefiles-using-an-attribute-value-in-qgis-gra)

Comment: I'd have suggest this solution, too, if OP hadn't stated they didn't want/need a single file for each feature.