# Splitting shapefile into multiple by value from field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, shapefile, attribute-table, split-by-attribute

I am working in QGIS. I have a shapefile and its table and I need to export each row as a new file called `"Fecha"` field:

[image: attribute_table]

Finally, I will get 6 shapefiles such as *20130612.shp*, *20130714.shp*, ...etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using the PyQGIS.

Let's assume there is a point layer called `'random_points_test'` with its corresponding attribute table, see image below

[image: input]

**Do not forget to change the layer and field names at the bottom of the code, i.e. `split_layer('CMillor_ldcRefAuto_2013_WGSUTMH31','Fecha')`**

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor > New Editor` and paste the script below

```py
# imports
import os, sys

# setting up the input layer and defining required parameters
def split_layer(layer_name, field_name):
    # loading layer
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
    layer_fields = layer.fields()
    idx_of_that_field = layer_fields.indexFromName(field_name)

    if not layer.isValid():
        raise ValueError("Layer failed to load!")
        sys.exit()

    # getting a set with unique key attributes
    list_attributes = []
    for feat in layer.getFeatures():
        list_attributes.append(feat.attributes()[idx_of_that_field])
    list_attributes = set(list_attributes)
    
    # checking a number of features in the input layer
    if layer.featureCount() < 2:
        raise ValueError("Layer contains only one feature. No reason to double save it")

    else:
        # getting a working dir, where the input layer is stored
        path_to_file = layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
        working_dir = os.path.split(path_to_file)[0]

        # looping over attributes from the set, selecting features and saving them as a new single layer
        for i in list_attributes:
            selection = layer.selectByExpression('{0}=\'{1}\''.format(field_name, i))
            writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, working_dir + "/{}.shp".format(i), "UTF-8", layer.crs(), driverName = "ESRI Shapefile", onlySelected = True)

    layer.removeSelection()

split_layer('random_points_test','Info')
```

Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output like this

[image: result]

A name of each output will match a pattern like *'<attribute_value>.shp'* e.g. *'Test 2'*, and should not *'<attribute_field_name><attribute_value>.shp'* i.e. *'Fecha_20130612.shp'* etc.

If you want to change the directory where the output should be saved, please create this folder beforehand, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-safely-create-a-nested-directory) for more details. And do not forget to apply changed in the `writer = ...`.

---

**References:**

- [Splitting up QGIS layer into multiple using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371828/splitting-up-qgis-layer-into-multiple-using-qgis)
- [Dividing shapefile into multiple shapefiles using an attribute value in QGIS Graphical Modeler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357776/dividing-shapefile-into-multiple-shapefiles-using-an-attribute-value-in-qgis-gra)

Answer (score 4):

Open the Processing Toolbox and try the [`'Split vector layer'`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#split-vector-layer) tool.

Set the Unique `"ID"` field to Fecha and the Output file type to shp (or another format if you wish).