# How to not include layer and field name when using Split Vector Layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, vector, splitting

When using "Split vector layer" tool, the outputs include the layer in the field name in the resulting shapefiles. The result file name is `'LAYER_FIELDNAME_ABC'`. I want to extract them so that the file name of the outputs will just be `'ABC'`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It is a PyQGIS solution https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/391188/99589 but I hope it can anyway help you. Please let us know if everything went smooth